# MySQL Syntax error: ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query where I want to order by shipping_date but I get this error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression 1 of 
    ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated 
    column 'device.devices.shipping_date' which is not functionally 
    dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with 
    sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select count(*) as device, 
    DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y") as year from `devices` where 
    `shipping_date` is not null and `internal_use` = 0 group by `year` order by `shipping_date` asc)
```

My code:

```
$sold_devices = Device::selectRaw('count(*) as device, DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y") as year')
                 ->whereNotNull('shipping_date')
                 ->where('internal_use', '=', 0)
                 ->groupBy('year')
                 ->orderBy('shipping_date', 'asc')
                 ->pluck('device', 'year');
```

any help?

Thanks

Comment: I think the error message is extreemly self explanitory

Comment: This is previous standard SQL that state _all fields in group by should be in select statement too_ so you could rename `shipping_date` in `year` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the exact `select` column in your `group by`: in your case

```
->groupBy('DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y")')
->orderBy('DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y")', 'asc')
```

Generally speaking, you can't use column aliases in `where`, `group by` and `order by` clauses.

**Edit**

To change the ordering criteria you can use the numeric value of the month instead of its name:

```
->groupBy('DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y")')
->orderBy('DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%Y%c")', 'asc')
```

Comment: @JasonJoslin Noted, thanks! I'm not sure about MySQL, but in some dbms you can also sort by position. Don't know what's the difference between position and alias for the database though

Comment: still not working, I get this error: 'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y"' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as device, DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y") as year from 'devices' where 'shipping_date' is not null and 'internal_use' = 0 and 'devices'.'deleted_at' is null group by 'DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y"' order by 'DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y"' asc)` @StefanoZanini

Comment: I was missing a couple of parentheses, sorry. I fixed it, try again :)

Comment: I know that I already fixed it in my code as I said I still get the same error message, and I tried another way it's working but its not what I am looking for. It orders it by Alphabetic and I want it yearly. See Image [link](http://i.imgur.com/9IupsH9.jpg) @StefanoZanini

Answer (score 0):

let's try this.

it will work...

```
 ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y")'))
   ->orderBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(shipping_date,"%M %Y"))','asc')
```

Comment: Your code orders it Alphabetically but I want it Yearly. See it [link](http://i.imgur.com/iJX00uI.jpg)